# Input to Levels Function - R

Tags: r

I have an Rscript that creates various 2D charts on a dataset.  I'd like to be able to change the X variable depending on which relationship I want to view.  So I made the X variable a command line argument.  Motivations aside, I want to be able to run the command:

```
scoreData <- read.csv(..)
xVarString <- args[0]
levels(paste(scoreData$,xVarString,sep=""))
```

but it simply returns NULL.  I know paste returns a string.  I know levels() does not accept a string.  What I dont know is the type that the levels function accepts.  I have tried

```
levels(as.vector(paste(scoreData$,xVarString,sep="")))
levels(as.list(paste(scoreData$,xVarString,sep="")))
levels(as.data.frame(paste(scoreData$,xVarString,sep="")))
```

As a general question, is there a place that shows R function input / output / documentation, similar to the .NET documentation and Java docs?  I have found plenty of tutorials but no straight function documentation.

Thakns in advance.

Comment: Putting a question mark before the name of a function reveals its documentation. `?levels` or `?plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`levels` accepts vectors of class `factor` (the function `levels(x)` is really just shorthand for `attr(x, "levels")`.

You need to pass the actual column of data to `levels`. `"ScoreData$Column1"` will only pass the string (as you point out). You could do:

```
levels(scoreData[,xVarString])
```

Assuming `xVarString` is a string of the desired column name. An easier method is:

```
sapply(scoreData, levels)
```

To see all the levels separated by column.